# What is the difference deploying a site in web server or cloud?

Tags: php, web, cloud, hosting, web-hosting

I built a Website using PHP and want to deploy it on internet. I want to know what is the best option as to host on web server or cloud and what will be pros and cons doing that.

Resources needed for my site:

1. PHP
2. Mysql
3. Apache or lighttpd

My site is simple CMS with 10 pages (max).

Comment: Well .. "in cloud" is when you are not really certain where exactly the webserver is, but you are fairly confident, that it is on Earth.

Comment: i have not downvoted but i think the reason of downvote is you can easily get your answer via google.and i think you are confused with what is cloud,so its nothing but the clusters of virtual servers.http://online-storage-service-review.toptenreviews.com/top-ten-advantages-of-using-online-storage-services.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web server has defined hardware specifications, meaning that if too many users try to access it, it will fail to answer their requests.
Cloud hosting providers will restrict you in what you can do (what language, what APIs you can access, ...), but they usually allow for automatic scaling, meaning: If the first instance's ("server's") load exceeds a certain limit, a second instance may start automatically to handle half of the load, and so on.

A single server often is sufficient for PHP sites, but you may suffer the [slashdot effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect), i. e. a sudden peak of attention to your site may bring it down quickly.

Comment: They also charge you roughly 12x what you really need to spend to host your website.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the kind of application you are going to deploy and kind of resources you application need. Anyhow below are the points you need to consider to decide cloud vs non-cloud.

1) Availability 
2) Scalability 
3) Security 
4) Cost effective

Prons:
1) Security
2) Limited control.

Comment: updated my post with required resources.